# Builds not appearing in build server

Tags: codenameone

I am building an android apk via 'Send Android build' and it shows that the build is successful. When I go to check the build server, it shows that it's empty.. Apparently with no build.

This is output in my console:

```
ant -f /home/falcon/NetBeansProjects/bizapp_mobile build-for-android-device
Generating GUI sources
No GUI Entries available
init:
deps-clean:
Updating property file: /home/falcon/NetBeansProjects/bizapp_mobile/build/built-clean.properties
Deleting directory /home/falcon/NetBeansProjects/bizapp_mobile/build
refresh-libs-impl:
Deleting directory /home/falcon/NetBeansProjects/bizapp_mobile/lib/impl
Deleting directory /home/falcon/NetBeansProjects/bizapp_mobile/native/internal_tmp
clean:
copy-android-override:
Created dir: /home/falcon/NetBeansProjects/bizapp_mobile/build/classes
copy-libs:
Copying 12 files to /home/falcon/NetBeansProjects/bizapp_mobile/build/classes
deps-jar:
Updating property file: /home/falcon/NetBeansProjects/bizapp_mobile/build/built-jar.properties
JavaFX Not loaded.  Classpath=/home/falcon/.codenameone/designer_1.jar . Adding to classpath
Adding JavaFX to your project properties file at nbproject/project.properties
JavaFX should be correctly loaded the next time you run this project.
Restarting JVM with JavaFX in the classpath.
NOTE: If you are trying to debug the project, you'll need to cancel this run and try running debug on the project again.  JavaFX should now be in your classpath.
JavaFX is loaded
Retina Scale: 1.0
Updating merge file /home/falcon/NetBeansProjects/bizapp_mobile/css/theme.css.merged
Input: /home/falcon/NetBeansProjects/bizapp_mobile/css/theme.css
Output: /home/falcon/NetBeansProjects/bizapp_mobile/src/theme.res
Acquiring lock on CSS checksums file /home/falcon/NetBeansProjects/bizapp_mobile/.cn1_css_checksums...
Lock obtained
File has not changed since last compile.
Releasing lock
CSS file successfully compiled.  /home/falcon/NetBeansProjects/bizapp_mobile/src/theme.res
Compile is forcing compliance to the supported API's/features for maximum device compatibility. This allows smaller
        code size and wider device support
Created dir: /home/falcon/NetBeansProjects/bizapp_mobile/build/tmp
Compiling 42 source files to /home/falcon/NetBeansProjects/bizapp_mobile/build/tmp
Created dir: /home/falcon/NetBeansProjects/bizapp_mobile/build/empty
Created dir: /home/falcon/NetBeansProjects/bizapp_mobile/build/generated-sources/ap-source-output
Compiling 42 source files to /home/falcon/NetBeansProjects/bizapp_mobile/build/classes
warning: [options] bootstrap class path not set in conjunction with -source 8
1 warning
Copying 2 files to /home/falcon/NetBeansProjects/bizapp_mobile/build/classes
compile:
Created dir: /home/falcon/NetBeansProjects/bizapp_mobile/dist
Copying 1 file to /home/falcon/NetBeansProjects/bizapp_mobile/build
Not copying library /home/falcon/NetBeansProjects/bizapp_mobile/override , it's a directory.
Not copying library /home/falcon/NetBeansProjects/bizapp_mobile/lib/impl/cls , it's a directory.
Not copying library /home/falcon/NetBeansProjects/bizapp_mobile/lib/impl/stubs , it's a directory.
Not copying library /home/falcon/NetBeansProjects/bizapp_mobile/${cn1.javafx.path} , it can't be read.
Not copying library /home/falcon/NetBeansProjects/bizapp_mobile/native/internal_tmp , it can't be read.
Copy libraries to /home/falcon/NetBeansProjects/bizapp_mobile/dist/lib.
Building jar: /home/falcon/NetBeansProjects/bizapp_mobile/dist/BizApp.jar
To run this application from the command line without Ant, try:
java -jar "/home/falcon/NetBeansProjects/bizapp_mobile/dist/BizApp.jar"
Created dir: /home/falcon/NetBeansProjects/bizapp_mobile/native/internal_tmp
jar:
clean-override:
build-for-android-device:
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 11 seconds)
```

Where could I be going wrong?

**EDIT**

Now this is confusing...

When I ran 'Send Android build' when my PC is connected to internet, it gives that message I posted before.

So accidentally, I ran 'Send Android build' while my PC was offline and it passed that point and it showed me this pop up:
[image]

Now.. once I this pop-up shows, that's when I connect to internet and everything will flow as supposed to.

So its like, if I have internet connected right from the start, it isn't successful but if I connect to internet after showing me the popup of an invalid Android certificate, everything will work fine and the build will be in the build server.

But is causing this now?

Comment: Did you follow these instructions: https://www.codenameone.com/blog/tip-fix-issue-missing-builds.html ?
What are the values within Versions.properties in the project? Just to be 100% clear are you using this URL to view builds? https://cloud.codenameone.com/secure/index.html

Comment: Yes i followed the instructions for fixing missing builds. The values in Versions.properties are : #Sat Feb 20 09:33:22 EAT 2021
CodeNameOneBuildClientJar=168
CodenameOne_SRCzip=171
CodenameOneJar=171
JavaSEJar=171
CLDC11Jar=163   And I confirm that I am using that URL to view the builds

Comment: I have created a new project and it built very well which means the problem is with my specific project. I have updated the libs over and over but still no change.

Comment: That's odd. Is it possible your build size is large and it's failing as a result of that (if you're on the free account). Normally there would be an error message for this but it's possible this didn't work.

Comment: Kindly review the edit I have put.

Comment: I'm guessing you're failing on the size of the project which happens before the certificate check. If there's no internet we can't check the size restriction since we can't verify user level. It should still fail in the server though and eat up build credits

Comment: But the size of the build is 1044kb

Comment: If you get it under 1mb does it pass?